# Rails - Simple Form Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

For my application, users can create posts through a simple_form on the user's own show page.  I have validation in the post model that requires presence is true.  When no input is made, instead of getting error notifications telling me my field is blank, I get ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, Validation failed.

How do I get it to create error notifications on the form to tell me a field is blank?

See my code below.

**user.rb**

```
has_many :posts
```

**post.rb**

```
attr_accessible :user_id, :category
belongs_to :user
validates :category, presence: true
```

**view/users/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'posts/form' %>
```

**view/posts/_form.html.erb**

```
<p>Add Post:</p>
<%= simple_form_for([@user, @user.posts.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :category %>
    <%= f.submit "Add Post", :class => "btn btn-header" %>
<% end %>
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.build(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: 'Post was successful.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user) }
        format.json { render json: @post.user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Discussion section 8 here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-the-view

Answer (score 3):

`@post = @user.posts.create!(params[:post])` is the problem. The `create!` method validates the model you are trying to create, and then raises an exception if validation fails.

You should instead do:

```
@post = @user.posts.build(params[:post])

if @post.save
  # do some good stuff
else
  # do some bad stuff
end
```

This won't raise any exceptions and will work as you want it to. If you want to display messages for the things that have gone wrong then you will have to `render :new` instead (eg. http://blog.markusproject.org/?p=3313)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I got rid of the `!` and when I fail the validations, the page just refreshes.  No posts are made to the database as the validations fail, but it still executes the notice: 'Post was successful.' It also does not tell me that I failed the validations and that I left the field blank. What is wrong?

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code above following your instructions. So if I fulfill all validations, it saves, which is not the issue. It is when I fail the validations. If I do render:new, it goes to /posts/new, but I would want it to stay on users/show page while giving notifications of the field that is blank. I tried redirect but that leads to a page refresh.

Comment: Sorry you actually need to `render :show`, I didn't see how your views were structured. There will always be a page refresh btw unless you get JS involved.

Comment: Thanks. When I tried to do render :show in my `posts controller`, it is looking for template in my `views/posts/show`, but what I should be rendering is still my `view/user/:id/show` .